# Solving for two variables in the same for loop

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

So I have a situation in which I have two pieces of data I am trying to get from the same for loop (well I want it to come out of the same for loop to not have repetitive code).

I am searching for the finalFloor my array of data will take me too; but I am also looking for at what index in address[] the variable currentFloor becomes a negative value.

Below is my code and currently I am running this as two separate functions (floorCalculator & inTheBasement) that run identical code (don't want, not good coding practice) except for the end goal of what is being found. I'm really struggling at trying to figure out how to combine this. Any ideas or pointers? Thanks for the help!

```
/* ----------------- Declaration of Variables ---------------- */
var up = '('; // represents moving up 1 floor.
var down = ')'; // represents moving down 1 floor.
var input_form = $('#input-form');  // represents the html input form.
var userInput = input_form.find('#address-input'); // represents the finding of the user's input.
var input; // stores user input value.
var address = []; // stores user's input value as an array of characters.
var currentFloor = 0; // represents the current floor in the for loop, set to ground floor (0).
var finalFloor; // represents the ending floor from the instructions given.
var results = $('.results');  // represents the div .results for appending data to.

/* ----------------- Parent Function ---------------- */
$(document).ready(initLoad);

/* ----------------- Child Functions ---------------- */
function initLoad()
{
  input_form.submit(function(event) // Listens for submission event at #input-form.
{
event.preventDefault();   // Prevents default method of html element.
takeInAddress();          // Calls function.
});
};


function takeInAddress()
{
  input = userInput.val();    // Stores the user input found at #address-input as var input.
  userInput.val('');          // Clears the input field for next user input.
  address = input.split('');  // Splits the string input into single characters stored now in the array address[ ].
  floorCalculator();          // Calls funciton.
};

function floorCalculator()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++)
  {
    if (address[i] == up)  // For any '(' present at the current index...
    {
      currentFloor++; // Increase the value of currentFloor by 1.
    }
    else if (address[i] == down) // For any ')' present at the current index...
    {
     currentFloor--; // Decrease the value of currentFloor by 1.
    }
  } // end for loop
  finalFloor = currentFloor; // Store the value of currentFloor now as finalFloor.
  // console.log(finalFloor);
  results.append('<h2>Floor to deliver to: ' + finalFloor + '</h2>'); // Append finalFloor value to .results html.
  inTheBasement();  // Calls function.
};

function inTheBasement()
{
  currentFloor = 0; // Resets currentFloor to zero.
  for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++)
  {
    if (address[i] == up) // For any '(' present at the current index...
    {
      currentFloor++; // Increase the value of currentFloor by 1.
    }
    else if (address[i] == down)  // For any ')' present at the current index...
    {
      currentFloor--; // Decrease the value of currentFloor by 1.
      if (currentFloor < 0) // if currentFloor becomes a negative value...
      {
        // console.log(i);
        // Append value of i
         results.append('<h2>When you will arrive in the basement: ' + i + 'th instruction. </h2>');
         break; // break from loop
       } // end if loop
     } // end else if loop
   } // end for loop
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your first loop is a classic use case for "reduce": it turns an array into a single value.

reduce takes a function, and an optional base value:

```
[1,2,1,1].reduce(aFunction, startValue)
```

We're going to write a function that, when passed to reduce, adds all values of an array together. The function we pass into reduce should accept two values--a 'memo' that will store state between the function calls, and be passed between them, and a 'value' that will represent the next value into the array, passed one by one. It should return whatever the state is after it has taken the value into account, and whatever it returns will be passed into the function again on the next call, along with the next value in the array.

```
function aFunction(value, memo) {
   return value + memo;
}
startValue = 0; // we start with 0 for our use case
```

We can make the function syntax shorter, like this:

```
(memo, value) => value + memo
// the return statement is implicit in this syntax
```

As a result, passing our function and our start value becomes a one liner:

```
[1,2,1,1].reduce((memo, value) => value + memo, 0)
```

The only other piece of knowledge necessary is the ternary:

```
(memo, value) => value === ")" ? memo + 1 : memo - 1
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
function (memo, value) {
    if (value === ")") {
        return memo + 1;
    }
    else {
        return memo - 1;
    }
}
```

Finally, if we want to do this all in one reduce call, we just need to pass a little more state along in our memo, and do another evaluation.

```
ourInput = ")()()((())))))()()()(".split("");
// it's now an array, as you know
state = { floor: 0, basementTrigger: false, becameNegative: undefined };
result = ourInput.reduce( (memo, value, index) => {
    memo.floor += value === "(" ? 1 : -1; // add either 1 or negative one to our floor
    if (!memo.basementTrigger && memo.floor < 0) {
        memo.becameNegative = index
        memo.basementTrigger = true;
    }
    return memo;
}, state)  // state is passed in as 'memo' on the inner functions's first call
```

For every value, this:

- either adds or subtracts from floor, based on whether `value` is `"("`.
- if the trigger is false, and the floor is negative, it:

  - flips the trigger to true, and stores the current index

then we just add:

```
output += ("result = " + result.floor);
if (result.basementTrigger) output += ("follow instruction: " + result.becameNegative)
```

Hopefully this helps on an alternative take to the question.

*disclaimer: did not proofread or test code, may be mistakes; my goal isn't to give you code anyways, but to show you concepts. This is a hacky rendering thrown up quickly, but should illustrate the tools you can use on your own.*

Comment: yes it is a string of 7000 parentheses in which ( is up a floor and ) is down a floor. So I pass the string into .split("") to split the string into 7000 characters and stored them in the array address[ ]. Then figured the easiest way to solve would be to use a for loop to iterate through the array while asking if "up" or if "down" then +/-1 to my current floor. Could you explain the piece of code you sent? I'm still pretty new to JS & jQuery.

Comment: Gladly, but first: I think I understand your code now--can you clarify to make sure? you want the 'basement' to return 0 if it was ever negative, and not return anything otherwise?

Comment: @Cody, let me know if this works. Completely rewrote answer. I believe I've understood your code, but you'll have to let me know.

Comment: This is absolutely awesome! Had to reread it a few times to make sure I got the concepts of .reduce() and the object state down pat but this is super cool man! And yeah you understood correctly. When I get a chance tomorrow I will update my code and play around with this concept. I'll make sure I comment it out for future reference. Major thanks man, love learning cool new ways to do things!

Comment: My pleasure. Reduce is a little tricky at first, but it's incredibly powerful once you know it. I love teaching as much as I love learning, glad to share it with someone who gets it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check for `currentFloor < 0` in the first `for` loop. To keep from printing the message twice, use a variable to remember if you already did it.

```
function floorCalculator()
{
  var foundBasement = false;
  var basementStep;
  for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++)
  {
    if (address[i] == up)  // For any '(' present at the current index...
    {
      currentFloor++; // Increase the value of currentFloor by 1.
    }
    else if (address[i] == down) // For any ')' present at the current index...
    {
     currentFloor--; // Decrease the value of currentFloor by 1.
     if (currentFloor < 0 && !foundBasement) {
        foundBasement = true;
        basementStep = i;
     }
    }
  } // end for loop
  finalFloor = currentFloor; // Store the value of currentFloor now as finalFloor.
  // console.log(finalFloor);
  results.append('<h2>Floor to deliver to: ' + finalFloor + '</h2>'); // Append finalFloor value to .results html.
  if (foundBasement) {
    results.append('<h2>When you will arrive in the basement: ' + basementStep + 'th instruction. </h2>');
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks! I felt like putting the currentFloor < 0 inside the else if statement was correct; but couldn't figure out a way to solve it without iterating every negative instance of currentFloor. I really appreciate the help and will make note of this strategy!